# Is it legal for an IT technician to register a Microsoft Office serial key onto his Microsoft account that I purchased?

Tags: legal-research

Good day,

I bought an office 2016 microsoft product from an IT store in 2018, or rather a work colleague did and I ended up taking over the whole process of sorting it out.

Until recently we've had no issues, and we ended up taking the notebook in to have the office 2016 issue sorted out, they told us there has to be a format and all sorts of technical mumbo jumbo that will cost us money in order for them to resolve the issue.

not being clued up with how microsoft product registration and such works i did some research and contacted microsofts support team, they helped me sort out the product without any problems, now I'm at the menu where I've to provide the login credentials for my purchased office 2016 product..

Upon purchase in 2018 the tax invoice has a username and password but not the purchased serial key, speaking to microsoft they said the provided username(email address) is not associated with the product we purchased, and in the research i found that the IT store registered the serial key to their own microsoft account!

I don't want to add too much, but bottom line, upon purchase they provided us with incorrect details, did not include the serial key of the purchased product and now when calling the guy that I need to speak to is apparently 'not in' the entire time. I'm wondering if it's illegal for them to register a product we purchased onto their name ?

So the above is my first primary question, I'll just add some additional train of thought here, I believe they registered it onto their account so that they can cause issues with the account and cause us to go in and claim all sorts of problems just so they can bill us, which seems like another illegal move ?

Comment: This question would be better suited to your work's IT department. They'd be better equipped to handle any issues made by a Microsoft support agent.